# Rails method for having a safe sum for enumerable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Rails provides a very convenient construct for allowing the summation of elements of an array.

```
foo = [1,2,3]
foo.sum
=> 6
```

However, you aren't always sure if your array will have non nil values, in that case the above method fails

```
bar = [1,2,nil,4]
bar.sum
TypeError: nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
```

Is there anything like a safe_sum that ignores the nil values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Array#compact`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) method:

```
bar.compact.sum
# => 7
```

or, you can go with [`Enumerable#inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject):

```
bar.inject(0) { |sum, el| el ? sum + el : sum }
# => 7
```

Although the first approach looks much prettier and more convenient to me.

Comment: Just for the sake of argument, what could be done if there were any non-numeric elements present?

Comment: @AnkitDhingra you mean strings, for example?

Comment: Yeah. It could be strings and nil and numbers all interspersed together.

Comment: @AnkitDhingra both of my approaches wouldn't work. Nevertheless, the second one would after slight modification:
`bar.inject(0) { |sum, el| el.is_a?(Integer) ? sum + el : sum }`

Comment: @AnkitDhingra, another answer to your question placed in comment came into my mind now:
`bar.select { |el| el.is_a?(Integer) }.sum`

Comment: Like this one more because of the conciseness...I love ruby so much after moving away from Java!

Answer (score 1):

You can even use compact

```
bar.compact.sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   module Enumerable
      def safe_sum(identity = 0, &block)
        if block_given?
          map(&block).compact.sum(identity)
        else
          reduce { |sum, element| sum + element.to_f } || identity
        end
      end
    end
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.